# Calling all the getters from an entity

Tags: php, symfony, dynamic, call, getter

After using:

```
$queryResult = 
    $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('EtecsaAppBundle:Paralizacion')
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->getQuery();
        ->setDQL($myOwnQuery)
        ->getResult();
```

I have an array of entities for which I want to use all their property getters. I'm doing this like this:

```
foreach ($queryResult as $index => $itemEntity)
{
    $objWorksheet->SetCellValue('A'. ($index + 17 ), $index + 1);
    // ... The itemEntity class has entity relationships associations 
    $objWorksheet->SetCellValue('B'. ($index + 17 ), $itemEntity->getSomeRelatedProperty()->getSomeProperty());
    // ... it also has properties with several types (date, string, etc)
    $objWorksheet->SetCellValue('C'. ($index + 17 ), $itemEntity->getSomeProperty));
    // Also some of the values obtained from his respective getter require some processing
    $objWorksheet->SetCellValue('D'. ($index + 17 ), getProcessedValue($itemEntity->getSomeSpecificProperty));
}
```

The letter used in SetCellValue function will also increase. I'm putting this as an example.
Is there a way to dynamically call all the getters of the entity, so I don't have to call them one by one? Something like this for example:

```
foreach ($queryResult as $index => $itemEntity)
{
    $columnLetter = 'A';
    $objWorksheet->SetCellValue($columnLetter++ . ($index + 17 ), $index + 1);

    arrayOfGetters = getArrayOfGetters(itemEntity);
    foreach (arrayOfGetters as $getterMethod)
    {
        // properties that reference an entity relationship association would have the __ToString function
        $objWorksheet->SetCellValue($columnLetter++ . ($index + 17 ), /* get value of getterMethod */);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @JovanPerovic

Sorry ... I'm asking for a way to dynamically call all the getters of the entities, so I don't have to call them one by one

Comment: I think people are down-voting your question because it's somewhat vague. I think the crux of your question is clear based on the title (hence my submitted answer) but is the following "The letter used in SetCellValue function will also increase" part of the question? If so, please clarify and I will try to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Darragh I just updated my question to show what I'm trying to pull off here. I think I can put your answer to good use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a PHP-general answer which should work in your case. Try this:

```
<?php

class Entity
{
    public function setFoo($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}


$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setFoo('foo!');

$getters = array_filter(get_class_methods($entity), function($method) {
    return 'get' === substr($method, 0, 3);
});

var_dump($getters);
```

Given any plain old PHP object, you can use [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) to get a list of all methods on an object that are visible in the scope where `get_class_methods()` is called - in this case all `public` methods.

Then we filter over this array of values and only return the getters.

For the above example, this yields:

```
array(1) {
  [1] =>
  string(6) "getFoo"
}
```

Now you can call your getters dynamically, like so:

```
foreach ($getters as $getter) {
    echo $entity->{$getter}(); // `foo!`
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: One thing to note: afaik, `get_class_methods()` will return the name of static methods too. Probably not an issue in your case since you're unlikely to have static getters and setters. But it's worth pointing out!

Comment: One question @Darragh where can I get some info about the use of {} on this `$entity->{$getter}()`

Comment: Hi, Actually, in this case it's completely redundant, so you can just use `$entity->$getter()` instead. I was going to edit it out actually, but then I figured it might illustrate that you can use a string value as a placeholder for a callable on an object. Sometimes people don't see the `->$` :)

Comment: In any case, you can find out more in the [Strings documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Look for the title **Complex (curly) syntax** (there's no page anchor, something that irks me about PHP's docs). It provides some examples of how the `{$myvar}` syntax "allows for the use of complex expressions". To reiterate, it's actually completely redundant here because of the syntax rules for function and method names so feel free to remove it!